# How to make a draggable canvas using the translate method?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a game map move like google maps.

I can't understand why I don't drag to the bottom or up, but only to the left or right, where you can read information about it or see formulas, but please don't throw off links to complex and cumbersome code that I can't even figure out.

My attempt

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const drawRects = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'aqua';
  ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 1000, 1000, 1000);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'magenta';
  ctx.fillRect(1000, 0, 1000, 1000);
}


const mouse = {
  isDown: false,
  isUp: false,
  isPressed: false,
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

const pos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}


function tick() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  
  canvas.width += 0;
  
  if(mouse.isPressed){
    ctx.translate(mouse.x - pos.x, mouse.y - pos.y)
  }
  
  drawRects()
  

  
  requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  pos.x = e.offsetX;
  pos.y = e.offsetY;
  
  
  
  mouse.isDown = true;
  mouse.isUp = false;
  mouse.isPressed = true;
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if(!mouse.isDown) return;
  
  mouse.x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.y = e.offsetY;
})

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  mouse.isDown = false;
  mouse.isUp = true;
})


tick()
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

I will be glad of any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to track the current translation of your canvas, in addition to the new delta.  Right now, what's happening is that everything you mousedown, you set pos.x=e.offsetX, pos.y=e.offsetY, mouse.x=e.offsetX, and mouse.y = e.offsetY.  Then in your next tick() method, you do `ctx.translate(mouse.x - pos.x, mouse.y - pos.y)` = `ctx.translate(e.offsetX - e.offsetX, e.offsetY - e.offsetY)` = `ctx.translate(0, 0)`, which resets your canvas to its starting position.

So adding an additional object to track the translation

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const drawRects = () => {
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'aqua';
  ctx.fillRect(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'green';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 1000, 1000, 1000);
  
  ctx.fillStyle = 'magenta';
  ctx.fillRect(1000, 0, 1000, 1000);
}


const mouse = {
  isDown: false,
  isUp: false,
  isPressed: false,
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

const pos = {
  x: 0,
  y: 0
}

const trans = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
}


function tick() {
  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
  
  canvas.width += 0;
  
  if(mouse.isPressed){
    // translate the canvas by its base position + the delta of the current mouse drag event
    ctx.translate(trans.x + (mouse.x - pos.x), trans.y + (mouse.y - pos.y));
  }
  
  drawRects()
  
  requestAnimationFrame(tick)
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
  pos.x = e.offsetX;
  pos.y = e.offsetY;
  
  mouse.isDown = true;
  mouse.isUp = false;
  mouse.isPressed = true;
})

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  if(!mouse.isDown) return;
  
  mouse.x = e.offsetX;
  mouse.y = e.offsetY;

    
})

canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
  mouse.isDown = false;
  mouse.isUp = true;

  // save off the new translation when we mouse-up
  trans.x += (mouse.x - pos.x);
  trans.y += (mouse.y - pos.y);

  // need to reset the mouse's starting and current positions before we start another drag event
  pos.x = 0, pos.y = 0, mouse.x = 0, mouse.y = 0;
})

tick();
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your attempt to help, are there any ideas to debug your solution?

Comment: Turns out the canvas.width += 0 actually was necessary (although I think I would recommend doing clearRect or something instead, as resetting the width like this seems like a hack, but regardless).  Should be working now.

Comment: thank you very much, you helped me a lot, I've been suffering all day with this, I couldn't figure out how to do it, I'll study your code